# when I use spark-sql, this error will appear

Tags: apache-spark-sql

when I use spark-sql, sometimes will go wrong, but sometimes will not
this is the error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException No filter named         org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter

how to solve this error, thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please add more logs, and few lines of code around which _Spark_ fails